# vue-yandex-map перемещение метки

Tags: vue.js, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Подключил vue-yandex-maps,  пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы по клику на точку создавался маркер и я получал его координаты, для дальнейшей передачи на сервер. Координаты клика получить удалось, а вот поставить маркер - нет. При том желательно, чтобы маркер был только один, при создании он уже стоит на определённых координатах, и если я кликаю в другое место - старый маркер удаляется, новый появляется. 2 часа гуглил на двух языках, решение не нашёл, на гите всего 3 issue на тему vuejs + yandex map.

Answer (score 1):

Привет!
Как я вижу решение: по клику ты получаешь координаты и передаешь маркер с пропсами из этих координат в карту либо через слот, либо через пропсы. На оба действия карта отреагирует, перерисовавшись с новым маркером. При изменении координат маркера - карта также будет перерисовываться, поскольку подписана на слежение за этими изменениями. 
В целом - не понимаю, почему у тебя возникла с этим проблема.
Если что - создавай issue в репозитории vue-yandex-maps, там я быстрее отвечу =)
С уважением.